# How to clear a column value after value is added from one row to another

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a tile-based game in c# using MySQL as my database. Currently I have a grid of buttons that updates the database every time a user clicks a button. The method called updates the table and sets current player on the tile to the name of a player. So far I can click go across many tiles and it updates the database, but it puts the player name on every tile that the player clicks. Is there a way that I can update a row and set a column to be a value, while removing that value from the previously updated column?

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_tile` (
    `tileID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `boardID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `tileNumber` INTEGER default null,
    `tilePlayer` varchar(100) default null,
    PRIMARY KEY (`tileID`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`boardID`) REFERENCES `tbl_board`(`boardID`) ON DELETE CASCADE 
);
```

and here is my procedure that updates the table:

```
drop procedure if exists UpdateDataTile; 
delimiter //
create procedure UpdateDataTile(IN `username` varchar(100), `currentTile` int)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE `tbl_tile`
        SET
        `tilePlayer` = username
        WHERE `tileID` = currentTile;

    END//
delimiter ;
```

Here is what it currently does:

[Data results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiW9O.png)

As you can see, the name is added to a new row every time the procedure is called. Id like it to only display the name once on the current tileID. I believe that I would need to update the row and set the column to null, but Im not sure how I would do this

Comment: Provide initial sample data as INSERT INTO (3-5 rows). Then provide the info for data change and show desired final data state.

Comment: I have a simple procedure that inserts into tbl_tile 71 times with a default value of null for tilePlayer. All of the rows say null until the procedure stated above is called. This then updates a single row based on what currentTile is. Each time currentTile updates, the stored procedure is called. Im trying to figure out how to update the rows that have previously been modified to be null. The desired result would show that there are 71 rows, where one has a username, whereas the rest say null

Comment: The data results link has an image as I cant upload one with my current reputation

Comment: Not writting an answer because I lack experience on mysql, but in sql server it would be similiar to: a) changing the WHERE to make the update results include the new and the previous value `WHERE tileID = currentTile OR tilePlayer = username` and b) change the SET so it does both the cleanup and the assignment `SET tilePlayer = CASE WHEN tiIeId = currentTile THEN userName ELSE NULL END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible question interpretation.

Initial data:

| tile | player |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | Jim |
| 4 | NULL |
| 5 | NULL |
| 6 | John |

John moves from tile 6 to tile 4. Needed final state

| tile | player |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | Jim |
| 4 | John |
| 5 | NULL |
| 6 | NULL |

The query:

```
UPDATE gamedata t1
JOIN gamedata t2
SET t2.player = t1.player,
    t1.player = NULL
WHERE t1.player = 'John'  -- player name
  AND t2.player IS NULL   -- the tile to move to is empty
  AND t2.tile = 4;        -- the tile to move to
```

If final tile is not empty then move is not performed.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e6ce798ff6127a1b8d2c67e908ecdaef

Comment: Spot on. Thanks :)